# draw Method for Spannable String doesn't get called on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout, spannablestring

I have a Calendar inside my Application. The Calendar is a GridView with Buttons for every date. I tried to color them with the following class

```
public class CircleSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

private final float mPadding;
private final int mCircleColor;
private final int mTextColor;

public CircleSpan(Context context) {
    super();
    TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{
            R.color.current_day,
            android.R.attr.textColorPrimaryInverse
    });
    mCircleColor = ta.getColor(0, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.current_day));
    //noinspection ResourceType
    mTextColor = ta.getColor(1, 0);
    ta.recycle();
    mPadding = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_circle);
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    Log.d("CircleSpan", "getSize");
    return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end) + mPadding * 2); // left + right
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        Log.d("CircleSpan", "empty draw");
        return;
    }
    float textSize = paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    paint.setColor(mCircleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(x + textSize / 2 + mPadding,
            (top + bottom) / 2, // center Y
            (text.length() == 1 ? textSize : textSize / 2) + mPadding,
            paint);
    paint.setColor(mTextColor);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, mPadding + x, y, paint);
    Log.d("CircleSpan", "draw");
}
```

}

I created the class and tested it with a Lollipop Test Device and everything worked fine. After that I put the Application on my device with Marshmallow. The entries inside the Calendar which should have a color weren't visible anymore. I found out that the draw method inside my CircleSpan class didn't even got called.

With a little "hack" i was able to get it working but I'm really not satisfied by the solution. It consists of a TextView that is not visible on the end of the screen which also gets colored with the CircleSpan. The difference consists of an extension of the text and just color everything except the extension:

```
                // Absolutly hacked
        SpannableString spannable1 = new SpannableString(theday + " ");
        spannable1.setSpan(new CircleSpan(gridcell.getContext(), ColorType.NONE),
                0, theday.length() - 1,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mHack.setText(spannable1, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

As long the "hack" is inside the App everything else got colored like I coded it. But I'm really not sure why. I've read about the ReplacementSpan in the Android documentation: [ReplacementSpan getSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ReplacementSpan.html#getSize(android.graphics.Paint,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt))

But the clue

> Returns the width of the span. Extending classes can set the height of the span by updating attributes of Paint.FontMetricsInt. If the span covers the whole text, and the height is not set, draw(Canvas, CharSequence, int, int, float, int, int, int, Paint) will not be called for the span.

doesen't help me. Does anyone has an idea how its possible to color the entries of my calendar with my class and without the "hack"? And why is the problem just on Marshmallow Devices? I'm not sure about Nougat and whats happening on devices below Lollipop.

I hope everyone can understand my poor English. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does no one has an idea? Is this a known bug maybe?

Comment: Faced the same bug, but have no idea about a decent workaround. May be you've found a solution, Lars?